# How to convert a multinomial logistics Predicted values into expected values?

Tags: r, multinomial, logistics

I have a continuous variable which I divide in 3 class. Now I have run the multinomial logistics model to predict the occurrence of any particular class.
My question is can I convert the predicted probabilities of multinomial logistics model to calculated a continuous variables. If yes, what is the formula of the same.
In the binomial distribution the expected values is calculated as np. Can I use the same logic here too?
For example: I have a score which range from 0-2 in my historical series. I classify it in 3 classess (0-06, 0.6-1 and >1) and run the multinomial logistics model. If I will use the final model to score my testing data. I would get the output as a probability. Is there any way I can convert this probability into a numeric values which can represent my score?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks! I have provided the example of the scenario. please let me know if you would need further details on the same